# List of strings to binary and back again

Tags: erlang

I've stumbled on a quite irritating problem;

I'm trying to generate a binary of a string-list and back again. Eg

```
erlang:binary_to_list(erlang:list_to_binary(["hello", "world"])
```

This will return "helloworld" and not a list with two different elements. Does anyone have any ideas of how to solve this? One solution might be to encode every element, but there might be a more elegant solution for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you have to encode it somehow. Here's the simplest way to do it by encoding it into Erlang binary term format

```
erlang:binary_to_term(erlang:term_to_binary(["hello", "world"]))
```

Comment: Ah. Why didn't I think of that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Strings are merely a list of ints in erlang those the concat done by list_to_binary.